# How to log userId in a server that handles concurrent requests?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, logging, serverside-javascript

I have an express server, and it handles all kind of functionalities that I want to log. I dont want to log only incoming requests, I want to log for example how much time it took for a certain function that handles data to execute. I also have a client that passes username as a header to each request in the server, and I want the username to be a part of every log. I can't store the username in a class or a global variable, as it won't be correct when multiple requests from different users are made. My logger is a class that you can simply call in order to log, for example: logger.log("blah", payload)

I don't want to pass the userId to every function where I want to log, what can I do?

Things I thought to do:

1. pass userId to every function, though I don't want to do it
2. Maybe somehow make the req known to the logger? But I don't know how to do it correctly

Comment: "*I don't want to pass the userId to every function where I want to log*" - that's exactly what you should do. Alternatively, pass the entire `req`uest, or pass a logger instance that is configured with the username.

Comment: @Bergi but that means passing it through a lot of functions, is that my only option here?

Comment: There might be logging/tracing frameworks that hook on asynchronous functions and allow an implicit "context", in which this info could be stored, but that might be overkill.